# dyld: initializer function 0x10b7f89d0 not in mapped image

Tags: macos-sierra, gnupg, memory-mapped-files, dyld

Received the following error when doing `$ sudo make install` for GnuPG:

```
Making check in scd
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `check'.
Making check in dirmngr
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  check-TESTS
dyld: initializer function 0x10e4aa9d0 not in mapped image for /usr/local/opt/libgpg-error/lib/libgpg-error.0.dylib

/bin/sh: line 1: 54741 Abort trap: 6           ${dir}$tst
FAIL: t-ldap-parse-uri
```

[Used this as reference for installation](https://macgpg.sourceforge.io/docs/howto-build-gpg-osx.txt.asc)

Did `$ sudo make install` despite the error.

---

After installation, I tried:

```
$ dirmngr --version

dyld: initializer function 0x10c2199d0 not in mapped image for /usr/local/opt/libgpg-error/lib/libgpg-error.0.dylib`
```

So I reinstalled libgpg-error again by doing:

```
$ ./configure 
$ make
$ make check   ( all 7 tests passed )
$ make install
```

To check the version I installed:

```
$gpg-error-config --version
1.27
```

Everything seemed okay, so I tried the following: `gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-key 9741E8AC`

```
gpg: connecting dirmngr at '/Users/Bubblemelon/.gnupg/S.dirmngr' failed: IPC connect call failed
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No dirmngr
```

So to address this issue `gpg: keyserver receive failed: No dirmngr`, I found this [forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=190380) that said by doing this: `sudo dirmngr </dev/null` would resolve the issue.

But received the same error again:

```
dyld: initializer function 0x10b7f89d0 not in mapped image for /usr/local/opt/libgpg-error/lib/libgpg-error.0.dylib
```

---

**Question:**

How do I resolve this

`dyld: initializer function 0x10b7f89d0 not in mapped image for /usr/local/opt/libgpg-error/lib/libgpg-error.0.dylib`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a specific reason as to why you need to build from source, in most cases, the easiest way to install dependencies etc on a mac is to use homebrew. Brew is a package manager, kinda like apt or npm.

Here is a link to an article that does exactly what you are wanting to do, using Brew.

http://blog.ghostinthemachines.com/2015/03/01/how-to-use-gpg-command-line/

Comment: Thanks for the link! Yes, homebrew would be the easy way to do it. I don't have a particular reason for installing it from source, was simply curious.